# Using both NSApplicationSupportDirectory and NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: pdf, nsuserdefaults, nsfilemanager, ios6.1, nsdocumentdirectory

Here is the deal... I am creating an app (from another one of my apps) but I am altering to from using only the NSDocumentDirectory, which obviously allows the user to see all of the user files, to seeing only a few of the files... namely user created PDFs.
I have it working... but, nothing shows in the FileSharing/Documents window in iTunes.

First are the methods that invoke the NSApplicationSupportDirectory in the persistence model...

```
+(NSString *)getDocumentpath
{
    //NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}

+(NSString *) documentsDirectoryPath
{
    //NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return documentsDirectory;
}

+(void) copyResourceFileToDocumentsDirectory: (NSString *) fileName
{
    //NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL succeeded = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writablePath];
    NSError *error;

    //If file is not in the documents directory then only write
    if (!succeeded)
    {
        NSString *newPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        succeeded = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:newPath toPath:writablePath error:&error];

        if (succeeded == FALSE) {
            NSLog(@"%@ : copy failed", fileName);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@ : copy success", fileName);
        }
    } else {
            NSLog(@"%@ : already exists", fileName);
    }
}
```

This is the method for saving the PDF into the NSDocumentDirectory, which has not been changed from the other app...

```
- (NSString*)saveJournalToPDF:(UIView*)journal andName:(NSString*)name
{
    NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",name];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    ... // the rest of the data strings for creating the PDF

}
```

My question: how do I get ONLY the PDFs to be visible to the user without exposing the other data files? Right now, it seems that it is either all or nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I neglected one small detail... setting the app to actually share files! The app's info.plist did not have "Application supports iTunes file sharing" set to YES. (UIFileSharingEnabled). Such a simple fix!!!